# Check if indexed variable has a value assigned somewhere

Tags: maple, indexed

**Part 1**

If we have this

```
[> restart; a[5]:=23: a[7]:=41:
```

then

```
[> about(a); whattype(a);
a:
  nothing known about this object
                        symbol
```

but

```
[> print(a);
                 table([5 = 23, 7 = 41])
```

and

```
[> convert(a,list);
                        [23, 41]
```

So Maple does have enough information about variable **a** and its indexes somewhere. How can we check that information without printing?

For small indexes it's not a problem, but if `b[123457891234578912345789]:=789;` then how do we check if there is some index `i` for which `b[i]` has a defined value and what that index `i` is (without printing, i. e. not manually)?

**Part 2**

I'd like to be able to work with such variables inside a function and return such variable.
For example, let's say I want to increase all indexes by 1. If I know which indexes exist then I can do that

```
[> a[5]:=23: a[7]:=41:
   f:=proc(x) local y;
      y[6]:=x[5]; y[8]:=x[7]; y;
      end proc:
   b:=f(a); b[6]; b[8];
           b:=y
            23
            41
```

but often I don't know what indexes variable a has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several programmatic queries you can make,

```
restart;
a[5]:=23: a[7]:=41:

# test whether a is assigned
assigned('a');
                  true

# test whether a is assigned a table
type(a, table);
                  true

# test whether table a has any indexed values
evalb( nops([indices(a, 'nolist')]) > 0 );

                  true

assigned('a'[7]);
                  true
```

If you wish you can make such queries prior to attempting to access and utilize the indexed reference (ie. to check that it has an assigned value). For example,

```
if type(a,table) and assigned('a'[7]) then
  a[7];
end if;
             41

if type(a, table) then
  [indices(a, 'nolist')];
end if;
            [5, 7]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The two commands `type(a, table);` and `[indices(a, 'nolist')];` will solve the problem!

Comment: But it's still weird that a variable can have two different types at once since `type(a, symbol);`  and `type(a, table);` both return `true`. Isn't that a bug?

Comment: The reason that `type(a,symbol)` returns `true` (even when `a` has been assigned a `table`) is so-called last-name-evaluation. The old `table` datastructure got "lne" to allow certain functionality, eg. in-place behaviour as mutable structure when passed as a proc argument.  Some description of lne at:  https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=last_name_eval

Comment: Thanks, that link also explained the usage of **eval** for this. So I could use `whattype(eval(a))` for checking the final type and use `op(eval(a))` for extracting indices too (especially useful when need key=value format).

Comment: @acer what about when the indexing is done by double underscore, i.e. `a__7`? Is there a way to see what such indices of `a` have been assigned? In this case `a` is not a table anymore.

Comment: The double underscore suffix is NOT indexing. It happens to pretty-print in the GUI in a subscripted manner similar to that of indexed names. But it is not any kind of indexing. And assignment of such names will have no effect on whether `a` is a table. Those names are not directly related to the name `a`.  Note however that you can check whether a prefix is suffixed, as a `type` check. Thus you can extract from an expression suffixed names. Eg. `indets(f,'suffixed(a__)')` for some expression `f` that might contain, say, `a__7`, `a__13`, etc.